# TextFormField inside ExpansionTile loses data when ExpansionTile collapses in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Here is my code, I've created an `ExpansionTile` and it has a child `TextFormField`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OrderCreatePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OrderCreatePageState createState() => _OrderCreatePageState();
}

class _OrderCreatePageState extends State<OrderCreatePage> {
  String _userID;
  TextEditingController _controllerl;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: new Text("Create"),
      ),
      body: ExpansionTile(
        title: Text("Create"),
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "User ID",
              icon: Icon(Icons.face),
            ),
            validator: (val) {},
            controller: _controllerl,
            onSaved: (val) => _userID = val,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Whenever I type something into the `TextFormField` and collapse the `ExpansionTile`, the data in the `TextFormField` is lost. I'm using this type of UI because I have to create a big form getting a lot of details. If there is no `ExpansionTile`, then the user has to scroll a long way.

Comment: your `_controllerl` is null... is it what you want?

Comment: @pskink Is the controller necessary to maintain the child's state?

Comment: ok, first try to add initial value to your `TextFormField` constructor

Comment: When i use a initial value, it resets to the initial value after collapsing. Doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Ya!, it sets the field to initial value. But, I what I want is not the initial value but the value before collapsing

Answer (score 5):

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile/maintainState.html

```
ExpansionTile(maintainState: true, title: Text("text here"), ...
```

With this, the state of the children will be maintained after collapsing and opening.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by -  @pskink

In your Code Add under `TextEditingController _controllerl;` :

```
@override
  void initState() {
     super.initState();
    _controllerl = TextEditingController();
  }
```

So your Code will look like :

```
class _OrderCreatePageState extends State<OrderCreatePage> {
  String _userID;
  TextEditingController _controllerl;
  @override
      void initState() {
         super.initState();
        _controllerl = TextEditingController();
      }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Scaffold(
       ....
       ......
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use some sort of ScrollView to display the input fields.

The following is stated in the [ExpansionTile reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html):

> This widget is typically used with ListView to create an "expand /
>   collapse" list entry. When used with scrolling widgets like ListView,
>   a unique **PageStorageKey** must be specified to enable the ExpansionTile
>   to save and restore its expanded state when it is scrolled in and out
>   of view.

So adding a PageStorageKey should do the trick:

```
ExpansionTile(
        key: PageStorageKey('myInputField'),
        title: Text("Create"),
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              labelText: "User ID",
              icon: Icon(Icons.face),
            ),
            validator: (val) {},
            controller: _controllerl,
            onSaved: (val) => _userID = val,
          )
        ],
      )
```